# Regex Pattern Using Brackets

Tags: c#, regex

Simple question here guys. I'm attempting to create a pattern to use with a Regex in C#.

Here is my attempt:

```
"(value\":\[\[\"([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-{0,1})[A-Za-z0-9]+)\"\]\])"
```

However for some reason when I go to compile this I get "Unrecognized escape sequence" on the brackets. Can I not simply use \ to escape the brackets?

The strings I'm searching for have the form of

```
value":[["AB-AB"]]
```

or

```
value":[["ABAB"]]
```

and I'd like to grab group[1] from the results.

Comment: you could do `Replace("[[",",").Replace("]]",",").Split(",");`  No reason reason for regex with something so simple.

Comment: Unfortunately that is just part of a much larger string. The section I posted is the only part that matters, thus why I'm looking for that specific pattern.

Comment: Basically what's happening is the C# compiler is trying to find out what `\[` means. It might be a valid escape sequence for a Regex pattern, but it's not a valid escape sequence in a C# string. Ultimately, you need to double up on your backslashes so that the compiler sees `\\[`, which gets turned into `\[` for the Regex pattern. _Edit: Or as the answers below show, just use a string literal with `@` and double up on your quotation marks instead_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend placing your pattern inside a verbatim string literal while implementing a negated character class to match the context; then reference the first group to grab the match results.

```
String s = @"I have value"":[[""AB-AB""]] and value"":[[""ABAB""]]";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"value"":\[\[""([^""]+)""]]"))
         Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Output

```
AB-AB
ABAB
```

Comment: How will Groups function when multiple matches are found?

Comment: Use `Matches` method instead `^^^`

Answer (score 3):

The C# compiler by default disallows escape sequences it does not recognize. You can override this behavior by using "@" like this:

```
@"(value\"":\[\[\""([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-{0,1})[A-Za-z0-9]+)\""\]\])"
```

Edit:

The @ sign is a little more complicated than that. To quote @Guffa:

> A @ delimited string simply doesn't use backslash for escape
>   sequences.

Furthermore it should be noted that the replacement for `\"` in such a string is `""`

Comment: That won't exactly override the behaviour. A @ delimited string simply doesn't use backslash for escape sequences.

Comment: Very true. I was actually just about to work on an edit to expand that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I didn't know about the double quote replacement.